# I show the selected items of a listbox in a textarea, but when i modify the textarea value, it stops working

Tags: javascript, razor, listbox, textarea, selecteditem

I have the next code to show the selected options of a listbox in a textarea:

```
$(".listBoxClass").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("#listBoxID option:selected").each(function () {
            str = $(this).text() + " \n";
        });
        $("#textAreaID").append(str);
    }).trigger("change");
```

And it appereantly works, but if I delete a word, or make any change in the textArea, the code stop working, so if I select other item in the listBox it doesn't appear in the textArea... I need to allow the option for the user to modify the textArea value, so he can put the values manually as well

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain what "stop working" means, exactly. Are errors reported in the developer console? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Could you add your html as well?

Comment: Why are you appending to a textarea? Is it an actual <textarea> ? Or is it a div?

Comment: Please add the missing HTML, not the code implementing the HTML but the actual rendered HTML as it is hard to derive what it might look like from your code.

Comment: Here it is the html code:
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                @Html.ListBox("listBoxID", (MultiSelectList) ViewBag.CodigoClase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control listbox; listBoxClass", multiple = "multiple", @rows=20, style="height: 200px; width:100px" })                
            </div>
           <div class="col">
               @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.CodigoSegmento, new {style="height:200px;width:100px"})               
           </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the append function you can insert content to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. So you can't use this function for change the textarea value.
Simply use the following script:

```js
$(".listBoxClass").change(function() {
    $("#textAreaID").val( $( this ).val() )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" class="listBoxClass" id="listBoxID">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textAreaID"></textarea>
```

Comment: And what if I need to keep the previous values the user has select? But also that he can add some values manually

Comment: for keep the previous value:     $(".listBoxClass").change(function(){var previous_value =$("#textAreaID").val();$("#textAreaID").val($(this).val())});

Comment: Thanks!!!! It works that way (creating the var previous_value and set the val of the textarea with the previous_value and the new selected item)

$(".listBoxClass").change(function () {        
        $("#listBoxID option:selected").each(function () {
            var previous_value = $("#textAreaID").val();
            $("#textAreaID").val(previous_value + "\n" + $(this).val());
            
        });
       
    }).trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the value of the textarea, not appending to it. And you are not concating it to the string, you keep replacing it in every iteration.

```js
$(".listBoxClass").change(function() {
  var str = "";
  $("#listBoxID option:selected").each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + " \n"; //concat it, do not replace, note the +=
  });
  $("#textAreaID").val(str);  //replace tha value
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" class="listBoxClass" id="listBoxID">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textAreaID"></textarea>
```

Comment: Actually I need to see all the items the user select in the textArea... Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure it does, but not after i do something on the textarea (like delete a word, or just a character)

Comment: well what you want to do than is a lot more than what your original question was about.... It really is impossible to know what user added and what was added by the select.

Comment: I just want to keep both... The selected items and the inserted manually... Is it possible?

Comment: How would you know what was added and what to remove? There is no easy answer to this.

Comment: Only the user knows ... The listbox contains a list of some codes useful to know what kind of products or services a person can offer to the company I work for... So, is a long long list... It is easy to the user to select the wrong code or maybe thinks it is easier to put it manually... So I need to find a solution for that... And I don't know what to do

Comment: So basically you should do if user selects something from the list, it gets added to the textarea and forget what is selected.  There are a lot of things that can be done, but they all would require a lot of code which I do not have time to even think about since I am trying to do my job.